# Checking which rows contain a value efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write a function that checks for the presence of a value in a row across columns. I have a script that does this by iterating through columns, but I am worried that this will be inefficient when used on large datasets.

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 3, 2]
c = [5, 6, 1, 3]
d = [1, 0, 0, 99]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,
                  'b': b,
                  'c': c,
                  'd': d})

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df['e'] = 0
for col in cols:
    df['e'] = df['e'] + df[col] == 1
print(df)
```

result:

```
   a  b  c   d      e
0  1  2  5   1   True
1  2  3  6   0  False
2  3  3  1   0   True
3  4  2  3  99  False
```

As you can see, column *e* keeps record of whether the value "1" exists in that row. I was wondering if there was a better/more efficient way of achieving these results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if values in the data frame is one and see if any is true in a row (with axis=1):

```
df['e'] = df.eq(1).any(1)
df
#   a   b   c   d   e
#0  1   2   5   1   True
#1  2   3   6   0   False
#2  3   3   1   0   True
#3  4   2   3   99  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Python supports 'in', and 'not in'.

EXAMPLE:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 5, 1]
>>> b = [2, 3, 6, 0]
>>> c = [5, 6, 1, 3]
>>> d = [1, 0, 0, 99]
>>> 1 in a
True
>>> 1 not in a
False
>>> 99 in d
True
>>> 99 not in d
False
```

By using this, you don't have to iterate over the array by yourself for this case.